# Excel formula for extracting prefixes

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, prefix

I have a table of 2 columns - file name & PC ID.
What I need is list of all 3-letter prefixes - for each PC ID separate. For example:

For:

```
BUSstop1  PC1
BUSstop3  PC2
TRMstop8  PC1
BIKnet1   PC1
```

I want to see something like this:

```
PC1:
BUS
TRM
BIK

PC2:
BUS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the formula `=LEFT(A1,3)` to column C.

Then, create a pivot table based on the data in the three columns. First drag the field with the PCs in the row field, then the field with the calculated 3 letter codes.

Done! :-)

Comment: They're by far the most powerful feature in Excel! Play around a bit - and in future you'll use it for every analyses that involve more than 10 rows and 2 columns of source data, I'll promise!